# Python arrow add hour/minutes/etc vs replace

Tags: python, arrow-python

I wanted to use `arrow` vs `datetime` in Python, and I want to convert the following example to `arrow`:

```
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=5)
```

The only thing I see in the `arrow` docs is:

```
start_date.replace(weeks=+3)
```

But I want to assign `end_date` with 5 days more than the `start_date` - not changing the existing `start_date`

I don't want to write i.e:

```
end_date = start_date
end_date.replace(days=+5)
```

I want to do it in a one-liner ... any idea ?

Comment: `replace(**kwargs)` - *"__Returns a new__ Arrow object with attributes updated according to inputs."* - http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/#arrow.arrow.Arrow.replace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`start_date.replace` doesn't alter `start_date`, it returns a new object. So you can just assign that to a new name:

`end_date = start_date.replace(days=+5)`

Reading the [docs](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/#arrow.arrow.Arrow.replace) is useful.

Comment: oops ... probably a bug in the script itself :/ sorry I'll delete my question

Comment: If you were actually doing `end_date = start_date` as you wrote in your question, then that's the bug -- that doesn't create a new date, it just makes both names (`start_date` and `end_date`) point to the _same object_ -- then if you do a `.replace` on `end_date` it affects `start_date` too. You should read [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, With arrow i assumed the todays date like

```
import arrow
start_date = arrow.utcnow()
```

Now I want to end_date is +5 days more to start_date, while start_date is unchanged.

```
end_date = start_date.replace(days=+5)
```

Is not this solved your problem?

Comment: Seems like while i'm writing @tzaman already given the answer! thanks.